# Calculate interest rate in Java (TVM)

Tags: java, math, iteration, formula

I've been working on a Java project which is calculator which can be used for calculating different scenarios of compound interest (very similar to the TVM Function found on a graphics calculator like [this one](http://www.casio.edu.shriro.com.au/products/fx9860gau/pdf/Self-Guided_9860_TVM.pdf))

The main function of the calculator is to calculate missing values using the known values in a formula. I have gotten all of the formulas working except for the one which calculates Interest rate (**I**)

I have done some research and apparently there is no straight formula to calculate the interest rate. This website: http://www.getobjects.com/Components/Finance/TVM/formulas.html shows the method i need to use, but it requires some iteration to find **I** using trial and error. (Check the link, Scroll down to the heading "Interest Rate Per Year")

Here is the structure I have set up for it:

```
public static double calculateI(double N, double PV, double PMT, double FV, double PY){
    //method for calculating I goes here

    return I;
}
```

I am not sure how to implement this, could someone please suggest how this can be done or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my code after the suggestion made by @rocketboy

```
public static double formulaI(double ip, double N, double PV, double PMT, double FV, double PY){
    double I1=(PV*Math.pow((1+ip),N))+((PMT*1)*(Math.pow((1+ip),N))-1)+FV;
    return I1;
}
public static double calculateI(double N, double PV, double PMT, double FV, double PY){
    double ip=0;
    double res;
    do{
        res = formulaI(ip,N,PV,PMT,FV,PY);
        ip=ip+0.01;
        System.out.println(res);
    }while(res!=0);
    double I=ip*PY;
return I;
}
```

Comment: You have the values being passed to the method use them with a combination of +, -, * and / to get the answer.

Comment: Few things: 1.What if res never becomes 0? For that you might want to relax your `res!=0` condition. In current code even if `res = 0.00000001` your loop will not terminate. OR exit after a set number of tries  2.what if the value returned by your `formulaI()` becomes  larger than a double? Same for `I = ip*PY`. Remember double calculations are not 100% accurate

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
double calculateI(/*all values for varialbles*/){
//definition;
}
```

Double.valueOf(d).equals(0.0);

```
long ip =0;
double res;

do{
   res = calculateI(ip, /*other constant values*/);
   ip++; /*Or you can increase ip according to your logic*/    
}while ( Double.valueOf(res).equals(0.0/*Expected result*/));
```

Edit: You have to handle the edge cases. The equation may not ever converge to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by definition?

Comment: method definition = content of your method. In your case the set of instructions to evaluate the result.

Comment: Yeah i thought that's what you meant, but it hasn't worked. I just get an infinite loop and no result.

Comment: How do you know your equation is converging at all? Will the result be exactly zero or should it falling in a range suffice, like `actual - extpected < 0.01`. Add some `System.out.println()` or breakpoints to debug.

Comment: Ok i added `System.out.println(res);` after the last step in the do-while and output looks like this:

-9931.93
-239790.1516169385
-5611060.635637154
-1.2732152441315554E8
(...)
-Infinity
-Infinity
-Infinity
(...)
NaN
NaN
NaN
(...)

(...) being more of the same stuff

(sorry does this comment make sense, comments don't allow for new lines)

Comment: Think about it, as `ip` increases, the equation is diverging and beyond one point you will overflow double. Should you be decreasing `i` after every iteration? If you still have trouble, I suggest looking up some basic java tutorials.