# How to find interest rate with payments

Tags: java, math

I need a formula to calculate interest rate involving payments, the other related formula as follows:

```
FV = (PMT * k / ip) - Math.pow((1 + ip), N) * (PV + PMT * k / ip);

PV = (PMT * k / ip - FV) * 1 / Math.pow(1 + ip, N) - PMT * k / ip;

PMT = (PV + ((PV+FV)/(Math.pow((1+ip),N)-1))) * ((-ip)/k);

ip = ????

Where:

PV = Present Value

ip = Interest Rate per period

N = Number of periods

PMT = Payment

k = 1 if payment is made at the end of the period; 1 + ip if made at the beginning of the period

FV = Future Value
```

Someone had asked the same question on [Calculate interest rate in Java (TVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178833/calculate-interest-rate-in-java-tvm), but still can't find correct answer.

The solution suggested is to substitute all known variables into the formula below, and then choose a series of values for ip until the expression equals zero:

```
0 = (PV * Math.pow(1 + ip, N)) + ((PMT * k) * (Math.pow(1 + ip, N) - 1) / ip) + FV
```

How to create a function to do the iteration or is there any straightforward formula to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure your formulas are correct.  Where are you getting them?  Regardless, these equations can't be explicitly solved for `ip`.  One approach would be to use Newton's method on whichever equation you want.

Comment: these formulas are tested and correct, it is from http://www.getobjects.com/Components/Finance/TVM/formulas.html

Answer (score 0):

The formulas can't be solved for `ip`; you're stuck using a root finder of your choice.  [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) would be as follows:

```
static double implicit(double PV, double ip, double N, double PMT, double k, double FV) {
    return PV * Math.pow(1+ip,N)
        + PMT * k * (Math.pow(1+ip,N)-1) / ip + FV;
}

static double dImplicit_dIp(double PV, double ip, double N, double PMT, double k, double FV) {
    return PV * N * Math.pow(1+ip,N-1)
        + PMT * k * ( ip * N * Math.pow(1+ip,N-1) - Math.pow(1+ip,N) + 1) / (ip*ip);
}

static double getIp(double PV, double N, double PMT, double k, double FV) {
    double ip = .1;
    double ipLast;
    do {
        ipLast = ip;
        ip -= implicit(PV,ip,N,PMT,k,PV)/dImplicit_dIp(PV,ip,N,PMT,k,PV);
    } while ( Math.abs(ip-ipLast) > .00001 );
    return ip;
}
```